# How to change font type face only in table environment?

Tags: tables, fonts

Why doesn't the `\ttdefault` change the font in the table?  I want to change font for a single table only.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\singlespacing
\footnotesize
\ttdefault
\caption{Some caption.}
\label{tab:xxx}\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\toprule
test1 & test2 & test3 \\
test1 & test2 & test3 \\
test1 & test2 & test3 \\
\bottomrule            
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\ttdefault` is not a font changing command; you probably want `\ttfamily`, put it just before the `tabularx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to have the *entire* table, including the caption, typeset in monospaced font, you can achieve this by inserting the sequence

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}\normalfont
```

immediately following the `\begin{table}` instruction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}\normalfont
  \caption{The table's caption} \label{tab:tt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  Header 1 & Header 2 \\ \hline
  1 & 2\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The braces around the macro to be redefined can be omitted, but those around the replacement text shouldn't. Omitting them works in this case, but only because of the current implementation of `\renewcommand`; don't trust on it forever.